# Retrofit: Getting java.util.NoSuchElementException occasionally

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using retrofit-beta2 and i get the below crash from time to time. Am not sure what am i doing wrong. It would be great if someone could give me a hint on fixing the problem.

```
Fatal Exception: java.util.NoSuchElementException
           at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:79)
           at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:164)
           at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
           at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
           at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:283)
           at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
           at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:286)
           at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:243)
           at com.squareup.okhttp.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:204)
           at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:232)
           at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:205)
           at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.access$100(Call.java:35)
           at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$AsyncCall.execute(Call.java:171)
           at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: did it work when you use others like version `1.9` or anything else

Comment: The code is completely different on `1.9` version isn't it... moreover this bug occurs only on rare occasions... I am finding it hard to track the cause :(

Comment: you mean sometime it works and sometime doesn't. Is it ?

Comment: @Shree Krishna - yep, you are right

Comment: @ok as the issue mentioned in answer try `2.6`.

Answer (score 1):

As said in [this](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2151) issue there is two possibilities:

> OkHttp has a bug where we’re attempting to recover when we shouldn't
>   be because we’ve exhausted all of the available routes.
>
> OkHttp has a bug where you’ve got a custom DNS implementation that 
>   returned zero IP addresses for a host and we didn't reject that.

My suggestion is to use new versions of retrofit and okhttp, because Retrofit 2 is already in release.

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.1.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'
```